# Kinect - GLView Symbol Lookup Error

Tags: kinect

I've done a manual install of the kinect system following http://openkinect.org/wiki/Getting_Started#Clone_libusb-1.0_Repo_and_Configure_Makefile and I've used the `freeglut3-*` instead of `libglut3-*`, but when I try to run `glview` I get an error:

```
glview
Kinect camera test
glview: symbol lookup error: glview: undefined symbol: freenect_select_subdevices
```

Comment: NO ideas yet... anyone? anyone?